# Rust Windows Crate CreateWindowExW

Tags: windows, rust, window, hwnd, crate

I am writing a function to create a window and I have provide the code which isn't working below. This code is using the [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate and the latest version of rust (at time of writing rustc 1.74.0.

```
use std::ptr;
 
use windows::{
    core::{w, PCWSTR},
    Win32::{
        Foundation::{GetLastError, HINSTANCE, HWND, LPARAM, LRESULT, WPARAM},
        Graphics::Gdi::HBRUSH,
        System::LibraryLoader::GetModuleHandleW,
        UI::WindowsAndMessaging::{
            CreateWindowExW, DefWindowProcW, DestroyWindow, PostQuitMessage, RegisterClassW,
            CS_HREDRAW, CS_VREDRAW, CW_USEDEFAULT, HCURSOR, HICON, WINDOW_EX_STYLE, WNDCLASSW,
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        },
    },
};
 
fn main() {
    match create_window() {
        Ok(_) => {}
        Err(e) => eprintln!("{}", e),
    };
}
 
pub fn create_window() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let h_instance: HINSTANCE = unsafe { GetModuleHandleW(None) }?.into();
    let lp_sz_class_name = w!("window_class");
    let lp_sz_window_name = w!("window_title");
 
    let window_class = WNDCLASSW {
        style: CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
        lpfnWndProc: Some(window_proc),
        cbClsExtra: 0,
        cbWndExtra: 0,
        hInstance: h_instance,
        hIcon: HICON(0),
        hCursor: HCURSOR(0),
        hbrBackground: HBRUSH(2),
        lpszMenuName: PCWSTR(ptr::null_mut()),
        lpszClassName: lp_sz_class_name,
    };
 
    if unsafe { RegisterClassW(&window_class) } == 0 {
        unsafe { GetLastError() }?;
    };
 
    let hwnd = unsafe {
        CreateWindowExW(
            WINDOW_EX_STYLE(0),
            window_class.lpszClassName,
            lp_sz_window_name,
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT,
            None,
            None,
            window_class.hInstance,
            None,
        )
    };
 
    if hwnd == HWND(0) {
        unsafe { GetLastError() }?;
    }
 
    Ok(())
}
 
unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: u32,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            unsafe { PostQuitMessage(0) };
            unsafe { DestroyWindow(hwnd) };
            LRESULT(0)
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            unsafe { PostQuitMessage(0) };
            LRESULT(0)
        }
        _ => return unsafe { DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam) },
    }
}
```

When this code is running it produces this as an error "failed to create window > The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)". Indicating that a parameter to the function `CreateWindowExW` isn't valid.

I've attempted isolate the parameters 1 by 1 but all have data, and I am unable to locate the invalid parameter. I was wondering if anyone can take a look and see if I have missed anything?

I expected the window class to be registered which is successful, and the handle to the window to be created which is unsuccessful.

Comment: You are not showing your `window_proc`, but `CreateWindowExW` will call it a few times before returning the newly created window handle, and any error on those could abort the operation. The most obvious being the [`WM_NCCREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate) message returning false.

Comment: ```
unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: u32,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => {
            unsafe { PostQuitMessage(0) };
            unsafe { DestroyWindow(hwnd) };
            LRESULT(0)
        }
        WM_DESTROY => {
            unsafe { PostQuitMessage(0) };
            LRESULT(0)
        }
        _ => return unsafe { DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam) },
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just tested your code and it worked for me. Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Please check the paste bin link https://pastebin.com/S2Lk0nPa i have removed some of the error handling to make it more generic. Add the features for the windows crate Win32_Foundation, Win32_System_LibraryLoader, Win32_Graphics_Gdi, Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging. This is producing the error on my system, and another local system i have, it's also happening in visual studio with C++ code. I'm going to format both machines and see if it makes a difference

Comment: This is basic Win32 code, not some advanced API, this kind of code has been working for almost half a century now. If your windows boots at all it _should_ work, unless you are doing something wrong. The pastebin makes it clear now, and I've posted an answer below. But now I'm intrigued with your C++ code, because a C++ `switch` doesn't show this Rust _weakness_...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the [mre]!

Comment: Never ignore warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled the MRE you pasted and it produces this warning that is a big red flag:

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:82:9
   |
77 |         WM_CLOSE => {
   |         -------- matches any value
...
82 |         WM_DESTROY => {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^ unreachable pattern
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unreachable_patterns)]` on by default
```

The relevant code is in `window_proc` is like this:

```
    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => { /*... */ ; LRESULT(0) }
        WM_DESTROY => { ... }
        _ => DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam),
    }
```

But the constants `WM_*` are unknown to the Rust compiler so this is actually equivalent to this:

```
    match msg {
        _ => { /*... */ ; LRESULT(0) }
        /* blah, blah DefWindowProcW something that is never run */
    }
```

That is, this function always returns `LRESULT(0)`, no matter what message is processing. And as I commented before, one of the first messages a window function gets, even before `CreateWindow` returns, is [`WM_NCCREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-nccreate). But returning `0` for that message will abort the window creation. The value returned by `GetLastError()` will be whatever you set with `SetLastError()` but you didn't call that, so you get meaningless error code.

The solution is easy, just import the message constants:

```
unsafe extern "system" fn window_proc(
    hwnd: HWND,
    msg: u32,
    wparam: WPARAM,
    lparam: LPARAM,
) -> LRESULT {
    use windows::Win32::UI::WindowsAndMessaging::*; // <---- Here!

    match msg {
        WM_CLOSE => { ...
```

That is why you should never ignore a Rust compiler warning. And why you should always add an MRE to a StackOverflow question!